# JsonConvert.SerializeObject adds \r\n

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

so currently I am working on a WebAPI and I run in the following error.

While I try to return a List serialized with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object) my second attribute (string JSON) get covered up by carriage returns and line feeds.

Here is the code:

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name;
    public string JSON;
}
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
    {
        var items = db.GetTemplates().ToList<Template>();


        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
        };
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return resp;

    }
```

Changing to:

```
Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items.ToList<Template>()[0]),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
```

Shows the same error

While changing the code to:

```
Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items.ToList<Template>()[0].JSON),Encoding.UTF8,"application/json")
```

Everything returns fine...

Checked in Browser, not in Visual Studio!

Anyone got a hint for me? Google just won't let me find the answer.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: One of the points of WebAPI is that you don't need to think about serialization in your action method. Change this to return `List<Template>` and let WebAPI handle serializing the correct response. You can configure it to return XML, JSON, ...according to the request.

Comment: Can you provide some json sample?

Comment: In the start, I let WEBAPI handle serialization - even though requirements changed and now I am in the need of HttpResponseMessages. Giving it a try though just resulted in the same error, following a tut on CodeProject.  Here is a Screenshot of the returnvalue: http://i.imgur.com/q6RlbqO.png

Comment: What error?  I don't see any errors here.

Comment: Json contains \r\n which it shouldn't

Comment: Have you tried using the `formatting` parameter of [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_1.htm) and setting it to `Formatting.None`?

Comment: I'll try it in the evening!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by Brian Rogers, Use JsonSerializerSettings Formatting = Formatting.None property:

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  Formatting = Formatting.None
};

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items,jsonSettings);
```